# Estou tentando atualizar um campo do banco de dados, pelo adapter. Como eu faço?

Tags: java, android, crud

...

```
public void concluirAtividade(Atividade atividade){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("SITUACAO", atividade.situacao);

        String[] parametros = new String[1];
        parametros[0] = String.valueOf(atividade.id);

        conexao.update("ATIVIDADES", contentValues, "ID = ?", parametros);
    }
```

....

```
public class ViewHolderAtividade extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public TextView txtAtividade;
            public TextView txtLocal;
            public TextView txtDataHora;
            public ImageButton imbExcluir;
            public ImageButton imbConcluir;
            public int requestCode = 0;
            public Atividade atividade;

            public ViewHolderAtividade (View itemView, final Context context){
                super(itemView);

                txtAtividade = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAtividade);
                txtLocal = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLocal);
                txtDataHora = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDataHora);
                imbConcluir = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imbConcluir);
                imbExcluir =(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imbExcluir);


                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (dados.size()>0){
                            Atividade atividade = dados.get(getLayoutPosition());
                            Intent it = new Intent(context, InsereAtividade.class);
                            it.putExtra("ATIVIDADE",atividade);
                            ((AppCompatActivity)context).startActivityForResult(it, requestCode);
                        }
                    }
                });

                imbConcluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(dados != null && dados.size()>0){

                            atividade = dados.get(getLayoutPosition());
                            atividade.situacao = "Sim";atividadeRepositorio.concluirAtividade(atividade);
                            Toast.makeText(context,atividade.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Não faça uma pergunta somente com código. Tente detalhar ao máximo o seu problema explicando em que parte do código está com problema e o que especificamente não está a funcionar

Comment: Tenho uma activity de atividades com 3 fragmentos, dois deles tem recyclerview. Estou usando como banco de dados o SQLite. Tenho na tabela um campo situação, que inicialmente eu carrego ele com "Não", para atividade não realizada. Eu quero alterar este campo para "Sim" quando clicar em um botão na recyclerview. Porém quando eu chamo meu método para concluir ativadade lança uma exceção NullPointerException, o que eu faço?

Comment: Poste a exception também. É tão ou mais importante que o próprio código.

Comment: A NullPointer exception está sendo lançada atividadeRepositorio.concluirAtividade(atividade);